# JSON deserialization problem - error parsing Instant

Tags: java, azure, date

I need to persist object in **Azure Table Storage**. Problem is I don't want to use Date type in my Entity class. I would like to use Instant but I have problems with parsing with the `JasonMappingException`.

Here is my entity class:

```
    @Data
    public class Event extends TableServiceEntity {
        @NotNull
        @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
        private Instant eventStart;
        @NotNull
        @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
        private Instant eventEnd;
        @NotBlank
        private String eventName;
        private String eventDescription;

        //default constructor
        public Event () {}
    }
```

And here is my deserializer:

```
    public class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Instant> {
        @Override
        public Instant deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
            String date = jsonParser.getText();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
            try {
                return sdf.parse(date).toInstant();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> 2020-06-10 20:47:19.685  WARN 11745 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-06-12T08:00:00UTC"; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-06-12T08:00:00UTC" (through reference chain: com.komix.eventmanager.model.Event["eventStart"])]

I am soo tired of the date problems with Azure DB. Could you please help me?

EDIT: Ok, after some edit parsing is fine but application gives me following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type class java.time.Instant is not supported.

It seems that Azure Table Storage doesn't support Instant??! I can't even find any good documentation for Asure Table data types supported...

Comment: I think there's a pretty solid chance the 'Z' in your simple date format should be lowercase. 

Look at the docs here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just using `jackson-datatype-jsr310`? (And, for that matter, `Instant.parse(String)`?)

Comment: How to use it in my case? Can you provide some sample please?

Answer (score 0):

`'Z'` is considered here as constants. You need to pass `z` without the quotes.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
```

Doc ref [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Did you try  this solution ?